# onActivityResult with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

So in my main `Activity`, using `Intent`, I start some `Service` object, which responds to some system event (and runs in a background of course) and sends a proper message to a registered `BroadcastReceiver` in the main activity. What I try to do is to `startActivityForResult` in the `onReceive` method in the broadcast receiver. The activity I'm interested in launching in `onReceive` is some other app, which processes my data (which is sent by the service to broadcast receiver) and returns back a success/failure message.

The problem is, that `onActivityResult` which is supposed to obtain the success/failure message, runs only when I open the main activity. What I want to do, is to get the result independently of whether my main activity is on the top or running in background (not on top of the stack). In other words, I want `onActivityResult` to be executed in the background.

Here's the idea (I omitted unnecessary parts and variables which work fine):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ...

    public BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(something)) {
                String text = intent.getStringExtra(some_key);

                Intent anotherApp = new Intent(some_configuration);

                startActivityForResult(anotherApp, request_code);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        // something should happen here

        // however this method fires only when MainActivity is on top
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Comment: @PetrR. - Thank you. I added a snippet with the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> What I try to do is to startActivityForResult in the onReceive method in the broadcast receiver.

Do not display an activity unless the user has clicked on something to cause that activity to appear. Do not interrupt the user in whatever else the user is doing without prior warning.

> What I want to do, is to get the result independently of whether my main activity is on the top or running in background (not on top of the stack). In other words, I want onActivityResult to be executed in the background.

That is not supported, sorry.

Comment: I'm not trying to interrupt the user. I just have to pass data to some app in background, and it is sent fine, but the message that I want to receive (also in background) using onActivityResult, requires my main activity to be on top. The whole purpose of my question is NOT to interrupt user and force him to go to my activity. That's the point. I just want to receive the result in background and display a notification.

Comment: @user2693529: "I'm not trying to interrupt the user" -- by your own admission, you are popping up an activity from a third-party app at a point when you are not in the foreground. That is going to interrupt the user, as *the third-party app* will be showing an activity. "I just want to receive the result in background and display a notification" -- then stop relying upon this third-party activity, and come up with some other way to get your result.

Comment: my whole app is an extension to that thrid part activity. I have to interact with it, and everything works absolutely perfectly, with one exception - the message of success/failure. I can display a notification and do whatever i need in the `onReceive` method, but I can't know the return message until the user opens my activity. I think, it is quite bad that there's no such a functionality. And again, it has nothing to do with disrupting the user.

Comment: @user2693529: "I think, it is quite bad that there's no such a functionality" -- then take it up with the third-party developer, asking them to give you an alternative to `startActivityForResult()` for doing this work (e.g., a service).

Comment: Alright, so background processing isn't possible. Is there any way to bring this activity to front automatically in the `onReceive` method? I've tried setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and changing `startActivityForResult` to `startActivity` but still I have to manually open the activity. Now this is a distraction, but I build this app for myself and I want the activity to pop-up immediately without any notification. In other words, is there any way to pop-up any activity (no matter external or not) in the `onReceive` method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2693529: "I've tried setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and changing startActivityForResult to startActivity but still I have to manually open the activity" -- that should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that I have just made on my android app which worked.

1. Create an empty Transparent activity and run it from your BroadcastReciever:

   ```
           TransparentActivity.setmOnActivityResultListener(this);
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, TransparentActivity.class);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. In your `TransparentActivity` `onCreate` method, add the code related to the activity that you want to start it with `startActivityForResult` ``

*example*

```
            TransparentActivity.setmOnActivityResultListener(this);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TransparentActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

3. In the same activity (`TransparentActivity`), override `onActivityResult`
   and you have to call another method which is a part of an interface you have to create as an inner interface in your `Transparentactivity`:

- 

```
public interface OnActivityResultListener{ 
 void send(Intent data);
}
```

- 

4. In `onActivityResult,` which we talk about it, call the *send* method:

- 

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
        case PressButtonBroadcastReciever.OVERLAY_PERMISSION_CODE:
            if(mOnActivityResultListener != null){
                mOnActivityResultListener.send(data);
            }
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

- 

5. Now, return the broadcast receiver class, and implement `send` method, and you can make your business logic with Intent Data receiver by the method